# PHP: Form post to api/auth with JSON payload (external website)

Tags: php, json, api, authentication

I am trying to work out how to post to a third-party website using a login form (username and password).

The only details I have from the provider is to POST to /api/auth with a JSON payload
{ username: "user@test.com", password: "userpass" } and if ajax call is successful redirect users to url.com/members

Can anyone give me some pointers/direction in order to do this?

I have found something like so:

```
$url = "https://url.com/api/auth";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: Basic cGF1bEB2aXN1YWxpbnRlbnQuY29tLmF1Okp1bXBpbmdKYW5lMjI=",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = <<<DATA
{
    "username":"username@email.com", "password":"password"
} 
DATA;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Which returns a successful message - but just have no idea on how to integrate into a form and then redirect the user to the third party website?

Comment: Why can't the users just log in to the third party site directly if you're just going to redirect them there anyway? Why should they post _their_ username/password to _you_ first? I would _never_ give away my credentials to a third party. That's how phishing sites operate and what every security expert are trying to teach people _not_ to do.

Comment: *Your server* is logged in to the third party site. You can only access their third party account on *your server*. Once you redirect *their client* (browser) to the third party site, and *their client* is no longer accessing *your server*, they will not be logged in to the third party site and therefore not have access to their third party site account. Their client needs to log in to get the third party site credentials directly.

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of AJAX post, whereby it posts their login creditentials over to the other URL and then logs them into that system? This website is a portal of sorts, but the client wishes to have the login for this portal on their site directly.

Comment: You should rather tell the client that it's a bad idea. First and foremost for the problem explained in the answer by @bloodyKnuckles, but also because there's absolutely no reason for the users to give them their credentials for a different site. Those credentials are between the user and that site, not your clients. Either just create a form that posts the credentials to the third site (if they allow that), or just have a link to the login.

Comment: You should rather tell the client that it's a bad idea. First and foremost for the problem explained in the answer by @bloodyKnuckles, but also because there's absolutely no reason for the users to give them their credentials for a different site. Those credentials are between the user and that site, not your clients. Either just create a form that posts the credentials to the third site directly (unless they have some CSRF protection), or just have a link to the login (which would be more appreciated by security aware users). It's our jobs as devs to educate clueless clients.

Answer (score 1):

> ...post to a third-party website ... (username and password) ... and
> then redirect the user to the third party website [logged in]?

It's not possible to log someone in to a third party website from an external website.

---

When one computer initiates a connection to another computer, in order to receive or send information, the initiating computer is considered the *Client*, and the other computer is considered the *Server*.

When a client logs in to a user account configured on a server, the server provides persistent credentials to the client so that each successive transfer of information is appropriate to the specific user account. The user account credentials, [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), in this case, are linked to a domain name. Only the server that hosts the domain name can write cookies to the client that are linked to that domain name.

Your server is acting as the client in the case you describe. Therefore the third party site is writing the user account credentials to your server and linking them to it's domain name.

Your server cannot take those credentials and write them to the client linked to the third party domain name.

Comment: You're absolutely correct in most parts, but many sites login use some form of cookie based sessions and doesn't necessarily be based on IP (since IP's are a poor identifier for multiple reasons and can even change during a single session). And in those cases, it will, just like you said, be the OP's server that would be the client and get the cookie. The browser won't receive anything and you can't set a cookie for a another domain than yours. So it's usually not the IP that's the issue.

Comment: @M.Eriksson  Thanks for correcting that! Please check my updated answer and let me know if I'm missing anything.